# require_once : failed to open stream

Tags: php, namespaces

I read on SO and experiment with some answers but my code does not work:
I have two classes:     `C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpdb\classes\dbconnection\mysqlconnection\MySqlConnection.php`
and     `C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpdb\classes\utilities\mysqlutilities\CreateTableDemo.php`.
In CreateTableDemo I have the following code:

```
    namespace utilities\mysqlutilities;
    use dbconnection\mysqlconnection\MySqlConnection as MSC;
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        $class = 'classes\\'.$class.'.php';
        require_once "$class";
    });
```

I get the following warning:

```
`Warning: require_once(classes\dbconnection\mysqlconnection\MySqlConnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpdb\classes\utilities\mysqlutilities\CreateTableDemo.php on line 10`.
```

I understand the warning, the script does not find the namespaced class in the same folder, so I changed the `spl_autoload_register` to look for a relative path: `__DIR__."\\..\\..\\classes\\.$class.'.php'`. I get the

```
warning: `Warning: require_once(C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpdb\classes\utilities\mysqlutilities\..\..\classes\dbconnection\mysqlconnection\MySqlConnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpdb\classes\utilities\mysqlutilities\CreateTableDemo.php on line 10`.
```

I cannot find a way to direct the script to the namespaced class.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a autoloader-class in a separate file:

```
class Autoloader {
    static public function loader($path) {
        $filename = __DIR__.'/classes/'.str_replace("\\", '/', $path).".php";

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            include($filename);
            $aClass = explode('\\', $path);
            $className = array_pop($aClass);           
            if (class_exists($className)) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::loader');
```

And include it in you index file (or whatever). 
It will load all your namespaced classes located in folder "classes".

```
require_once '/PATH_TO/autoload.php';
```

BTW: the trick is to replace the backslashes to regular slashes. 
Works fine for me.

EDIT: Place the autoloader.php at same level like your "classes" folder is. :-)

Comment: it works thank you. is that necessary to go through an autoloader to get it to work?

Comment: Glad to hear that :-) No, its not necessary, but i like it, because its a clean and classy way to load the required files.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because the path to the class is wrong relative to where you are requiring from. Try:

```
namespace utilities\mysqlutilities;
use dbconnection\mysqlconnection\MySqlConnection as MSC;
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $exp = explode('classes', __DIR__);
    $base = reset($exp);
    $class = $base."classes".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$class.".php";
    require_once $class;
});
```

Comment: `$base = reset(explode('classes', __DIR__)); ` I got an error on that line.  Only variables should be passed by reference